# draw an existing image as animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drawing

I'm trying to find a way to draw an image with the count down just like the tigers face in loading page on the site [run4tiger](http://run4tiger.com/) but once I started it didn't seem as easy as I thought it would be, using this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4kN6.jpg).

So I opted to use ms paint to cut and erase the image to create different frames and the plan was to use an online free gif maker to combine the frames and have the image looking like its being drawn where its only just a gif. so after a day and a half with +- 150 frames and no where near the end, I think I went about this the wrong way.
Any assistance, being pointed in the right direction would be highly appreciated

Comment: In the  WWF Tiger Challenge website, the images are drawn using SVG.